# Better way to subfile multiple files with similar titles?

Tags: loops, subfiles

I have a set of lecture notes and each lecture is contained within a subfile, and the main file contains a list of all the lectures like so:

```
\subfile{lec-1}
\subfile{lec-2}
% more files labeled lec-X
\subfile{lec-26}
```

Every time I need to set the view to certain lectures/the full document I would need to comment/uncomment manually, and I would like something that is a bit less tedious.

Are there any better ways to organize this? Perhaps a simple foreach loop would work, but are there any more elegant solutions? Thanks!

Comment: Please expand your code snippet into a MWE. // Sorry, don‘t understand your problem. Can you add examples to your question? Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You could use a `\foreach` from `pgffor` package for not repeating all the `\subfile`.

With `multiaudience` you can set two (or more) "audiences", that is versions of the document.
In my MWE, `complete` print everything, and `onlysome` prints subfiles 1, 3, and 4.

You can choose which one to use by simply commenting/uncommenting one of these two lines:

```
%\DefCurrentAudience{onlysome} 
\DefCurrentAudience{complete}
```

Here is the complete MWE:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{pgffor}
\usepackage{multiaudience}
\SetNewAudience{complete}
\SetNewAudience{onlysome} 

\usepackage{subfiles}

\begin{document}

%\DefCurrentAudience{onlysome} 
\DefCurrentAudience{complete} 

\begin{shownto}{complete}
\foreach \ind in {1,...,26}
    {\subfile{lec-\ind}}
\end{shownto}

\begin{shownto}{onlysome}
\foreach \ind in {1,3,4}
    {\subfile{lec-\ind}}
\end{shownto}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Nice, but isn‘t the TO asking for some kind of versioning?

Comment: @MS-SPO Better now?

Comment: For me: yes. Nice

Answer (score 0):

With `parts.sty` as given below, you can specify in the beginning, which parts to include, like so:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{parts}
\onlyParts{basic}
%\onlyParts{basic,advanced}% typeset all
\begin{document}
\Part{basic}{\subfile{lec-1}}
\Part{advanced}{\subfile{lec-2}}
\Part{basic}{\subfile{lec-3}}
\Part{advanced}{\subfile{lec-4}}
\end{document}
```

If you want to specify the included material by the number of the lecture, you can do it more succinctly with a custom command `\myPart`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{parts}
\newcommand\myPart[#1]{\Part{#1}{\subfile{lec-#1}}}
\onlyParts{2,4}
\begin{document}
\myPart{1}
\myPart{2}
\myPart{3}
\myPart{4}
\end{document}
```

Here is the code of `parts.sty`.

```
\newcommand\onlyParts[1]{\def\parts@only{#1}}
\onlyParts{}
\newcommand\Part[2]{%
  \def\parts@this{#1}%
  \@for\parts@that:=\parts@only\do{%
    \ifx\parts@this\parts@that
      #2%
    \fi  
  }%
  \ignorespaces
}
```

This utility is not restricted to loading subfiles, but you can use it with text and other code as well.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{parts}
\onlyParts{Monday,Wednesday}
\begin{document}
\Part{Monday}{On Mondays, we recover from the weekend. }
\Part{Tuesday}{On Tuesdays, we work from nine to five. }
\Part{Wednesday}{On Wednesdays, we prepare for the rest of the week. }
\Part{Monday}{On a second thought, we should also get something done on Mondays. }
\end{document}
```

[image]